# Drawing geographic map tiles with C#

Tags: c#, image, google-maps, iis, opentk

I am creating a privately consumed custom map overlay.
I cannot use an open source server like MapServer, because of the sheer volumes of data and the format that it is in.

Originally it was going to be a client-side solution that pushed an ArrayBuffer to the client and render the data on a map using WebGL, however we later found out that our users' PCs would be minus a GPU, so they cannot smoothly run the WebGL rendering.

So I took the concepts and applied them to OpenTK - I created an IIS server handler that creates an OpenTK instance, and renders a requested tile.

For prototype's sake, it works - however I feel this is not the best solution.

What is the most efficient way to render out tiles?
I would love to pre-render the tiles, but there are just too many datasets (adding 1000 more per day!) to be able to efficiently do this.

Is OpenTK a good route to go down (because of the hardware acceleration it can take advantage of?), or is there too much overhead in setting up an instance?

Or are the C# Graphics libraries a better route to learn and use?

Or even - is it worth ditching IIS and C# all together and using a different language/framework for serving the images?

Comment: webgl or OpenTk without gpu would have the same impact on perf...if you plan a web app, you'll surely better use webgl...

Comment: In this case, OpenTK is running on the *server* to prerender the tiles. The original idea was to render on the *client* via WebGL, but the lack of a GPU makes that impossible.

Comment: @Brad Zucher: how many concurrent users are you expecting? Would each user access different tiles? How long does one tile take to render? Can you design an efficient caching scheme? There are simply too many unknowns to give a concrete answer here.

Comment: @TheFiddler 100-1000 users. Mostly different, yes - lots of datasets. At the moment it takes ~0.4s per tile. If I put my mind to it I could design a decent caching scheme! But our proxies do a lot of caching too when I set the correct headers! I guess the main question is - are there enough overheads in starting up OpenTK for it to be quicker per tile to just render using .NET graphics?

Comment: Your server only has a single GPU, so launching multiple instances of OpenTK will be significantly slower than launching a single instance and queuing tiles for rendering. Context switching inside the GPU drivers hurts. The latest version of OpenTK starts up in milliseconds so that should not be a problem (but you will have to measure.)

Comment: @TheFiddler hmmm okay then, thanks. I didn't think about how much context switching would matter - I was more worried about initialisation. I guess the biggest initialisation overhead is the DB query then!! I've got to write a tile renderer for a separate set of data, so I'll get stuck into learning .NET graphics whilst I do that and then rewrite my OpenTK code after.

Comment: @TheFiddler I have finished the rewrite and the render times are exactly the same as my OpenTK code. Could you write it as an answer so I can accept it, because IMO it answered my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server only has a single GPU, so launching multiple instances of OpenTK will be significantly slower than launching a single instance and queuing tiles for rendering. Context switching inside the GPU drivers hurts. The latest version of OpenTK starts up in milliseconds so that should not be a problem (but you will have to measure.)

Comment: Drawing a single tile with the c# drawing library takes the same time (~0.4s) and drawing many tiles is a lot more stable. Thanks for pointing out the context switching.